# How do I press media keys with Java?

Tags: java, media-player, playback, pause

Or how do I send the same commands?

I want my app to be able to play/pause/etc. the currently-playing media **in a desktop environment** (Windows / macOS / Linux), but looking through [the keys](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#field.summary) that [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) can press, these aren't there.

I looked briefly at [jintellitype](https://github.com/melloware/jintellitype), but that doesn't seem to be what I want (something about running an Apache server?)

**Is there any way to press these media keys or send similar commands to the OS using Java*?** This can be anything in Java SE (AWT/Swing/FX/etc.) or some other free library.

---

<sub>* I'm actually using Kotlin, in case that helps</sub>

Comment: This is kind of a bear in native code I very much doubt there is a pure Java solution.

Comment: @pvg I'm hoping there's some library out there that utilizes Java's `native` to do this, but thanks for the heads-up

Comment: There might be but I think that's unlikely as well. Google around a bit for the native solutions to get an idea what a dark night full of horrors that stuff is. You can cheat a little though, for instance, on OS X, you can control itunes with applescript quite easily, etc.

Comment: @pvg Oh man that's promising for macOS!